# This bat file should renamed all files with bak extension to files of the same name with txt extension. But it doesnt work

Tags: batch-file, cmd

```
@echo off
for /r C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp %%i in (*.bak) do ren %%i %%~ni.txt
```

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the given code? What have you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: Try first changing ```C:\Users\Пользователь\AppData\Local\Temp``` to either ```"%LocalAppData%\Temp"```, or ```"%Temp%"```, then ```%%i``` to ```"%%i"```, and ```%%~ni.txt``` to ```"%%~ni.txt"```.